# combinatorics and geometry

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinations

how many different triangles with a perimeter of 15cm   can be constructed that have integral multiples of sides??

**MY APPROACH :**

(a+b+c)=15 and three sides(`integral multiples of sides`) are a , k$*$a(i.e. b), k$*$p$*$a (i.e c)

as the side are integral multiples so the equation becomes

a+ka+kpa=15

now i cant solve it???how to solve this??

Comment: "Integral multiples of sides" may be a mistranslation. It probably is integral sides. The sum of the two smaller numbers must be greater than the largest number. The largest number is therefore $\le 7$, and clearly $\ge 5$. Now list carefully and separately the cases (i) largest is $5$ (only $1$ possibility); (ii) largest is $6$; (iii) largest is $7$. (If we were dealing with a number much bigger than $15$, we would want to develop shortcuts.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas why `≤7, and clearly ≥5`

Comment: i will list on basis of what???will you please elaborate your views...what is the approach and why??

Comment: The sides add up to $15$ so the largest side must be $\ge \frac{15}{3}$. For the $\le 7$, if the largest side was $\ge 8$, that would leave $\le 7$ for the sum of the other two sides. But the sum of any two sides of a triangle is greater than the third.

Comment: I already did largest side $5$. Largest side $6$: There is $6,6,3$, and $6,5,4$, and no more because if second largest side is $\le 4$, the sides can't add up to $15$. Largest side $7$: There is $7,7,1$, and $7,6,2$, and only two more.

Comment: thanks..if you write it as a reply..i can mrk it as a correct answer :)

Comment: @AndréNicolas and one more thing how does the `integral multiples of sides` is holding in your approach

Comment: You can write it up as an answer. And if I find out you did, I will upvote.

Comment: I mentioned in the first comment that that is probably poor wording or a mistranslation. This is a standard problem type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with no restrictions $($ only $a,b,c ∈ \mathbb{N_0} )$, all the solutions of $a + b + c = 15$, are $\binom{14}{2}$, so $ \frac{14\cdot 13}{2} = 7\cdot 13$. Unfortunately we're dealing with triangles, so each solution should satisfy \begin{cases}
a + b > c \\
b + c > a \\
c + a > b \\
\end{cases}
Now, the simplest way to the solution would be counting the combinations not acceptable: you should go for cases (I know it's unaestethic, but this method will ensure you that you wouldn't miss any solution).

If $ a = 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8$ there are no solution (because $ b + c < a$) ... and so on.
With a little patience, a list of solutions can be formed: 
\begin{cases}
1-7-7 \\
2-6-7 \\
3-6-6 \\
3-5-7 \\
4-4-7 \\
4-5-6 \\
5-5-5 \\
\end{cases}
Finally it can be states that all the possible triangles can be only 7 (out of $7\cdot 13$ possible solutions with no restrictions !)